# stored procedure in teradata

Tags: sql, teradata

I have to create a stored procedure in teradata by using cursor.
Suppose there are 4 columns in table ,and the last column contain flag I.e Y and N.
I have to delete the row which contain flag y. By using cursor. 
Then I have to use update statement. Which changed the date value.
So can anybody help me on these ,how can I achieve this.
How can I write stored procedure in teradata.
Note:parameter is date.

Comment: Are you using MySQL, Oracle or Teradata?

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example to improve your question.

Comment: I am using Teradata

Comment: Why would you do this within a cursor when a `DELETE` statement would suffice? This feels like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).